# What is ambers uses?

Tags: terraria-mobile

When I was using a machine that uses silt blocks I got some Amber. What are the uses of Amber? I have heard of Amber bugs as well from my cousin. Like an amber mosquito. Are they real?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Amber):

> Amber is a type of Gem. Besides Orange Torches, Crate Potions, Amber
>   Gemspark Blocks and the Amber Staff it cannot be used to make anything
>   else other gems can be made into, such as Grappling Hooks or
>   Phaseblades. It can however be placed as a decoration like the other
>   gems.

*Note*: Not to be confused with the [Amber Mosquito](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Amber_Mosquito).

Comment: Thanks for the help! Reason I was confused was because the recipes hadn't come up yet. It must've been a bug.

Comment: You can show any items to the Guide, he will show you all the possible crafting recipes :)